# Adding new recipe in yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am new to Yocto and Embedded and wanted to something like this,

```
$ git clone https://github.com/babelouest/orcania.git
$ git clone https://github.com/babelouest/yder.git
$ git clone https://github.com/babelouest/ulfius.git
$ cd orcania/
$ make && sudo make install
$ cd ../yder/
$ make && sudo make install
$ cd ../ulfius/
$ make && sudo make install
```

Please help in creating layer and recipe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created the recipes and layer configuration to compile all the mentioned software.

Note: Dependency towards systemd is disabled by default. If you need to run in a system with systemd, you can enable them and add the support.

**conf/layer.conf:**

```
# We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"

# We have a recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
    ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "babelouest"
BBFILE_PATTERN_babelouest = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_babelouest = "6"

# Set a variable to get to the top of the meta-layer location
HAB_BASE := '${LAYERDIR}'
```

**recipes-babelouest/orcania/orcania_git.bb:**

```
DESCRIPTION = "Potluck with different functions for different purposes that can be shared among C programs"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/babelouest/orcania"
LICENSE = "LGPL-2.1"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=fc178bcd425090939a8b634d1d6a9594"

inherit cmake pkgconfig
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/babelouest/orcania"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

DEPENDS = "jansson"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "jansson"
```

**recipes-babelouest/yder/yder_git.bb:**

```
DESCRIPTION = "Logging library for C applications"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/babelouest/yder"
LICENSE = "LGPL-2.1"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=40d2542b8c43a3ec2b7f5da31a697b88"

inherit cmake pkgconfig
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/babelouest/yder"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

DEPENDS = "jansson orcania"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "jansson orcania"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DWITH_JOURNALD=off"
```

**recipes-babelouest/ulfius/ulfius_git.bb:**

```
DESCRIPTION = "Web Framework to build REST APIs, Webservices or any HTTP endpoint in C language. Can stream large amount of data, integrate JSON data with Jansson, and create websocket services"
HOMEPAGE = "https://babelouest.github.io/ulfius/"
LICENSE = "LGPL-2.1"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=40d2542b8c43a3ec2b7f5da31a697b88"

inherit cmake pkgconfig
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/babelouest/ulfius"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

DEPENDS = "gnutls jansson libmicrohttpd"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "gnutls jansson libmicrohttpd"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DWITH_JOURNALD=off"
```

This layer depends on following layers,

1. meta-openembedded/meta-oe
2. poky/meta

You can include them in bblayer.conf or name this layer as meta-babelouest and include. All the files are added to my github gist [here](https://gist.github.com/parthitce/a0ecc6ff869b62b3de84ce93386f89f0).

Comment: Seriously? Get some basics about yocto. Here you have three bitbake recipes, so you can compile them using `bitbake ulfius yder orcania`. babelouest is just the layer name. You can name it as anything.

Comment: Hi Parthiban, Thanks for the reply,
I added them and tried to compile using command "bitbake babelouest" but getting error "ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'babelouest' ",
--> I create meta-babelouest directory,
                              |_ conf/layer.conf
                              |_recipes_babelouest
                                        |_orcania/orcania_git.bb
                                        |
                                        |_yder/yder_git.bb
                                        |
                                        |_ulfius/ulfius_git.bb

Comment: @ShishirKumarSingh: Not sure why you have deleted your previous comment. Already answered!